# sensu checks with community plugins give an error while executing

Tags: chef-infra, sensu

The sensu checks fails to execute, the sensu client logs show the following error

```
checks dont work ("output":"/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory\n","status":127)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the embedded Ruby by setting `EMBEDDED_RUBY=true` in `/etc/default/sensu`. It works very well but only if you have ruby checks only. You cannot set embedded ruby setting for bash, python or other languages checks.

Answer (score 1):

the community plugins for sensu, use `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` this looks for the ruby executable under /usr/bin/env.

If you dont have ruby installed, and the only place ruby is either chef client or sensu client as embedded, then here is what you can do to fix it.

Create a symbolic link for ruby, such that the plugins can now find ruby to execute the code

`ln -s /opt/sensu/embedded/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby`

also ensure that sensu user has **execute** permission on the plugin/script

This is also mentioned in the [Sensu FAQ](http://sensuapp.org/docs/0.12/faq) section.

Comment: KrzysztofSzarek's answer is the correct way to do this. Symlinking system Ruby to Sensu's Ruby is unclean.